# Httparty headers

Tags: ruby, header, instagram, httparty

What is wrong with this?

```
HTTParty.get("https://www.instagram.com/#{username}/?__a=1", :headers => {"x-instagram-gis" => Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{rhx_gis}:/#{username}/")})
```

If I do the same thing using `curl` passing the headers via `--header`, it works.

```
curl "https://www.instagram.com/hossamhossny/" | grep "rhx_gis"
```

We can then grab `rhx_gis` value then MD5 `"<rhx_gis>:/username/"` as `"1ba367317d3c842eb4e940f1d62b29f2:/hossamhossny/"` to produce the value of `x-instagram-gis` as `"2830c5bff8e05b755724df2c6286f2b4"`.

Now with curl I can do that..

```
curl --header "x-instagram-gis:2830c5bff8e05b755724df2c6286f2b4" "https://www.instagram.com/hossamhossny/?__a=1"
```

Which produces the desired output..

```
{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_3669759838","show_suggested_profiles":false,"graphql":{"user":{"biography":"","blocked_by_viewer":false,"country_block":false,"external_url":null,"external_url_linkshimmed":null,"edge_followed_by":{"count":222},"followed_by_viewer":false,"edge_follow":{"count":55},"follows_viewer":false,"full_name":"Hossam SAld HossNy","has_blocked_viewer":false,"highlight_reel_count":0,"has_requested_viewer":false,"id":"3669759838","is_private":false,"is_verified":false,"mutual_followers":null,"profile_pic_url":"https://scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/6d079f6b5b60323cbfc4442c460d0e52/5BA22630/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13628116_1250649874979851_160235967_a.jpg","profile_pic_url_hd":"https://scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/6d079f6b5b60323cbfc4442c460d0e52/5BA22630/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13628116_1250649874979851_160235967_a.jpg","requested_by_viewer":false,"username":"hossamhossny","connected_fb_page":null,"edge_felix_video_timeline":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_owner_to_timeline_media":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_saved_media":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_media_collections":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]}}}}
```

Switching back to `HTTParty` I tried this:

```
HTTParty.get("http://www.instagram.com/#{username}/?__a=1", :headers => {"x-instagram-gis" => "2830c5bff8e05b755724df2c6286f2b4"})
```

but that didn't work either; 403 unauthorized error. My problem is that I am not able to pass the headers properly using HTTParty.

Comment: What do you mean by "_didn't work_"?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example that reproduces the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JagdeepSingh didn't work means it passes no headers at all and returning 403 unauthorized.

Comment: @Tom  I have edited my question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I recommend running the `curl` command which works with `--verbose` or `--trace`.  You may find there is more back-and-forth; `curl` will follow redirects, for example.  You would then have to implement whatever back-and-forth happens in your ruby code.  `curl` will also store and re-use cookies handed to it; you might have to do the same in your code.

Comment: I didn't miss trying curl with the -v but I am getting 200 Ok and SSL handshakes, nothing fishy like redirects or anything. I think I need to run the HTTParty one with a `verbose` option to get more debugging info. Let's not also forget that the code has actually worked for Rohan, so it should be something machine specific.

Answer (score 0):

The url with SSL returned error but below mentioned worked for me.

Try using it with http (without https)

```
HTTParty.get("http://www.instagram.com/#{username}/?__a=1", :headers => {"x-instagram-gis" => Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{rhx_gis}:/#{username}/")})
```

Comment: It does work for you exactly as is but using http? I have had issues on some other machine with https but when I passed `:verify => false` I managed to get passed through the SSL error. Can you try with that in https and let me know?

Comment: It still gives me forbidden even with http

Comment: are you able to open www.instagram.com in browser?

Comment: Yes, I am. Are you getting 200 ok and a json response?

Comment: yes..then it might be possible that you are unable to access the account of the particular user

Comment: nope, this doesn't work for me using any usernames. I am not sure how it can work for you but not for me, I was almost sure that I am doing something wrong passing the headers but obviously something else is wrong.

Comment: I have tried the same on another machine but it didn't work neither. Am I missing some gem? That's the only thing I can think of, even though if that's the case it should produce an error for me.